Connection broken: IncompleteRead in Google Cloud Run
I have a google cloud run service which is triggered via pubsub and grabs data from an azure api and places it in a gcp bucket using smart_open.
          with smart_open.open(destination, "wb") as fout:
            schema = pyarrow_adapters.json_schema_to_pyarrow_schema(self.desired_schema)
            data_frame.to_parquet(
                path=fout,
                engine="pyarrow",
                compression="gzip",
                schema=schema,
                use_compliant_nested_type=False,
            )

Edit:
This is the error I get in google-resumable-media-python
https://github.com/googleapis/google-resumable-media-python/blob/main/google/resumable_media/_upload.py#L50-L53
This saves 100s of thousads of files in a few hours time, each day there's a few failures with this error which I cannot figure out how to fix.

Retrieving Azure Metrics for Resource ID: xxx
Configuration is: xxx
Error retrieving metrics: Connection broken: IncompleteRead(15773 bytes read, 125469 more expected)', IncompleteRead(15773 bytes read, 125469 more expected))

And also sometimes a very similar error like this

Retrieving Azure Metrics for Resource ID: xxx
Configuration is: xxx
Error retrieving metrics: Bytes stream is in unexpected state. The local stream has had 8887 bytes read from it while 0 bytes have already been updated (they should match).

The metrics for cloudrun look good, and I have no idea how to debug this further.
Steps to replicate.

Setup a cloudrun service that runs a flask app with a single endpoint that picks up events from an eventarc trigger.
@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def index():
  data = request.get_json()
  if not data:
    msg = "no Pub/Sub message received"
    print(f"error: {msg}")
    return f"Bad Request: {msg}", 400

  if not isinstance(data, dict) or "message" not in data:
    msg = "invalid Pub/Sub message formaty"
    print(f"error: {msg}")
    return f"Bad Request: {msg}", 400

  pubsub_message = data["message"]


Use gunicorn to run this, Dockerfile
...
CMD ./azu_metrics_extractor_pex.pex \
    azu_metrics_extractor.main:app \
    -b :${PORT} \
    -w 3 \
    --threads=8 \
    --timeout=0


The service should use info in the pubsub message to grab resource data from azure, convert to parquet, and write it to a gcp bucket using smart_open
      with smart_open.open(destination, "wb") as fout:
        schema = pyarrow_adapters.json_schema_to_pyarrow_schema(self.desired_schema)
        data_frame.to_parquet(
            path=fout,
            engine="pyarrow",
            compression="gzip",
            schema=schema,
            use_compliant_nested_type=False,
        )


Trigger the pubsub topic with ~10k messages in one hour

Notice that roughly 2 or 3 of those parquet files that were to be saved to gcp failed to save with the above errors.


Potentially related to this open issue for smart_open
https://github.com/piskvorky/smart_open/issues/784

Have you tried updating gcloud ? Is your server running successfully on your local machine? Have you tried upgrading libraries/dependencies you are using? Also, can you share logs from google cloud?

Server runs successfully on my local machine, although it's hard to emulate the speed of the triggering that happens on gcp due to the pub/sub interaction.
Using the latest 7.0.4 of smart_open.
There isn't any other logs about the error than what I posted, only other output is info logs that I have, but have updated the post with them in case they are any help.

In that case, Can you share the steps you followed to replicate? Also elaborate about your approach/architecture?

Added more steps to reproduce.

We had this "connection broken" error in GCP Workflows calling cloud function. As you describe, 2 - 3 errors in 10k. We checked this with GCP support and their solution was to build a retry function. They admitted that it was network related (and maybe still is).
So we came up with a custom retry in GCP workflows and never saw this error again.
    retry:
      predicate: $${custom_retry}
      max_retries: 5
      backoff:
        initial_delay: 5
        max_delay: 60
        multiplier: 2

....
custom_retry:
  params: [e]
  steps:
    - retry_always:
        return: true

retry always sounds stupid but works in our case.
So in your cloud run code, you would need to catch the error and do a retry. Do you need help with that?

Thanks, this is actually what I was currently trying.
I have updated the retry decorator like this
@retry.Retry(predicate=retry.retry_base.if_transient_error or retry.if_exception_type(requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError) or (lambda e: isinstance(e, ValueError) and "Bytes stream is in unexpected state" in str(e)))
But it's not currently working (get the same error with no attempt at retry), will look into your retry suggestion here and see if that helps.

Thanks, retry worked, will update this with my solution tomorrow.
